# How to extract XML data from logs using Unix shell script?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, perl

My question is not related to the 
Parse XML to get node value in bash script?
Also i cannot install/use any new XML parser as per the company policy.
This needs to be achieved using shell/perl/awk/sed

I will try to rephrase my question:

1) We have a process.log file in which we have lot of text data and in between we have some XML data published.
2) There of thousands of different XML published in the logs along with other text data.
3) Now i need to select only the XML files which are published after **Outgoing XML:** value
4) Also the XML file which must be selected and copied to a new file should be the **one which matches the value in the ALERTID tag**.
5) The ALERTID value will be provided in the script input. So in our case **mGMjhgHgffHhhFdH1u4** will be provided in the input and we need to select the full XML file published for this alertid. Starting tag is from  and ending tag is 
5) So i need to select the relevant Outgoing XML file in a new file based on a particular ALERTID so it can be replayed in different environments.

> Format of the log:

```
Info Jan 11 17:30:26.12122 The process is not responding to heartbeats
Debug Jan 11 17:30:26.12123  Incoming XML :<xml version "1.0" encoding ="UTF-8"?>
<Alert trigger = "true" >
<Alerttype>orderReject</Alerttype>
<AlertID>ghghfsjUtYuu78T1</AlertID>
<Order>uusingas</Order>
<Quantity>1254</Quanity>
</Alert> (CreateInitEventHandler. C:356)
Debug Jan 11 17:30:26.12199 The process is going down with warnings
Debug Jan 11 17:30:26.148199 Outgoing XML: <xml version "1.0" encoding ="UTF-8"?>
<Alert trigger = "true" >
<Alerttype>orderheld</Alerttype>
<AlertID>mGMjhgHgffHhhFdH1u4</AlertID>
<Order>uwiofhdf</Order>
<Quantity>7651</Quanity>
</Alert>(CreateEventHandler. C:723)
Debug Jan 11 17:30:26.13214 The process has restarted and thread opened
Debug Jan 11 17:30:26.13215 The heartbeat is recieved from alertlistener process
```

Now the requirement is to take AlertID in the input, scan the process log and extract the matching outgoing XML in a separate file.

Using awk i am able to extract all the outgoing xml files but not sure how to extract the one  related to a particular AlertID.

Eg:

```
awk '/Outgoing/{p=1; s=$0} P & & /<\/Alert>/ {print $0 FS s; s="" ;p=0}p' 1.log>2.log
```

Comment: Use a real XML parser.

Comment: Any other way to do it?

Comment: No, really, use a real XML parser.  Using `awk` (which matches _regular_ expressions) is not going to be useful in extracting data from XML (which is _context free_).  If you don't know those terms, it means that _you cannot correctly parse XML with regular expressions_.

Comment: I've hesitantly voted to re-open. Please would you provide a decent example consisting of several of the log file entries from which you want the XML data to be extracted. The relevant parts are any preamble, the first two or three elements of the XML document, and the corresponding end. Please make it absolutely clear whether each log file entry is on a single line, or multiple lines. If a log entry covers multiple lines please explain (in words) what starts and ends a log entry.

Comment: Thanks for reopenig the question. I have now given more details how the log looks like. The logs and data is on mutiple lines. The data which must be extracted is from <xml version > and ending at </Alert> tag.

Answer (score 0):

One method which is **not** particularly well suited to the task, but should work, is this:

- Remove LF's so that everything appears on a single line
- But place a LF after `</Alert>` so that all XML's are in a row of their own
- `grep` for the desired code
- output the line and clean it up

This translates to:

```
 tr -d "\r\n" < log_file \
 | sed -e 's/\<?xml/\n&/g' -e 's/\<\/Alert>/&\n/g' \
 | grep -F '<AlertID>mGMjhgHgffHhhFdH1u4</AlertID>'
```

You can even pipe the result to `xmllint --format -` to pretty-print it.